# Not receiving data from AWS S3 Transfer Manger Download Request iOS SDK v2.0.5

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have all of the authentication issues worked out and I know that the credentials provided give access to all of my S3 buckets. When I run the code below, it runs without task.error, but the [task.result body] returns 0 bytes of data.

```
    AWSS3 *s3 = [[[AWSS3 alloc] initWithConfiguration:configuration] autorelease];
    transferManager = [[[AWSS3TransferManager alloc] initWithS3:s3] autorelease];
    getFileRequest = [[AWSS3TransferManagerDownloadRequest new] autorelease];        
    getFileRequest = [[AWSS3TransferManagerDownloadRequest new] autorelease];
    getFileRequest.bucket = @"MY_BUCKET";
    getFileRequest.key = @"MY_KEY";
        [[transferManager download:getFileRequest] continueWithExecutor:[BFExecutor mainThreadExecutor] withBlock:^id(BFTask *task){
            if (task.error != nil) {
                NSLog(@"Error: [%@]", task.error);
            }
            else {
                NSArray       *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
                NSString  *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
                NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data.dat"];
                NSData *data = [task.result body];
                NSString *download = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                NSError *error;
                [download writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error: &error];
            }
            return nil;
        }];
```

The only error that is posted to the log is

> AWSiOSSDKv2 [Error] AZURLSessionManager.m line:467 |
>   -[AZURLSessionManager URLSession:dataTask:didReceiveResponse:completionHandler:] | Error:
>   [Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=21 "The operation couldn’t be
>   completed. (Cocoa error 21.)" UserInfo=0xc67f840
>   {NSFilePath=/Users/firstname_lastname/Library/Application Support/iPhone
>   Simulator/7.1/Applications/number/tmp}]

Has anyone had a similar issue or see something in the code that was left out or is incorrect? If you need any other info feel free to ask

Answer:
I figured out the issue. As mentioned in the comments below, "DirectWrite" was turned on, so instead of putting the data into the task.result object, it looks for a file path under the "downloadingFileURL" property of the AWSS3TransferManagerDownloadRequest object. Below is the corrected code:

```
NSArray       *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString  *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"predata"];    
getFileRequest.downloadingFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
[[_transferManager download:getFileRequest] continueWithExecutor:[BFExecutor mainThreadExecutor] withBlock:^id(BFTask *task){
    if (task.error != nil) {
        NSLog(@"Error: [%@]", task.error);
    }
    else {
        NSError *error;
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath] error:&error];
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:path];
        NSString *download = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSMacOSRomanStringEncoding];
        [download writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error: &error];
    }
    return nil;
}];
```

Hope this can help someone else and thanks for the help @LyndseyScott and @YosukeMatsuda

Comment: Hm... I wonder if those autoreleases are executed before the async block is complete... What happens if you remove them?

Comment: I removed them and still get the same problem :( But thanks for the suggestion

Comment: If you are not using `defaultTransferManager`, you need to manually retain a strong reference to an instance of `AWSS3TransferManager`. One way to accomplish it is to make it a property. Also, you can change the logging level by calling: `[AZLogger defaultLogger].logLevel = AZLogLevelVerbose;`. Do you get additional logs?

Comment: Yes I got a ton more. One mentions something about DirectWrite being on and a warning that the data will be written to the "downloadingFileURL directly." Another one lists the metadata from the file I want to download, and its all correct so its finding the correct file. Also, both the transferManager and download request are properties in the header file.

Comment: What function/param in your solution above - turns off directWrites ?